# Find the sample size so that the probability that the mean sample does not differ from the population mean

Tags: probability

A researcher wishes to estimate the mean of a population using a sufficiently large sample so that the probability that the sample mean does not differ from the population mean by more than 25% of the standard deviation is 0.95. What size should the sample be taken?

**My attempt**
I think we need solve this using law of big numbers.

We know

$$P(|\bar{x}-\mu|>0.95)\leq \frac{25}{100}$$

this is equivalent to

$$P(|\bar{x}-\mu|\leq 0.95) > 1-\frac{25}{100}$$

Let $\epsilon=0.95$ and $\alpha=1-\frac{25}{100}$ then $1-\alpha=\frac{25}{100}$

The by law of big numbers we have:

$$n\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2(1-\alpha)}$$

Here i'm stuck because i don't know how to find $\sigma^2$ (variance)

Comment: You have numbers backwards. The probability is $0.95$ and the tolerance is $0.25$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson and how can i calculate $\sigma^2$

Comment: You don't seem to have understood Sean's comment, or at least you haven't edited the question to reflect it.  You want $$P(|x-\mu|\le .25\sigma)=.95$$